# Combining two different validation in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-validation, mslists

I have a List with multiple columns and want to do validation on 2 columns based on the value of a drop-down list and want to do validation on the list with the following conditions.

**Column 1** ( Type ) if value ( others ) is selected then the field shouldn't be blank

**Column 2** ( Location ) if value ( others ) is selected then the field shouldn't be blank

I am able to do only one condition at a time with this formula:

```
=IF([Type]="Others",IF([Other Type]="",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

Can you advise what will be the formula that will have both conditions?

Comment: Are you trying to make one field mandatory for both conditions or two separate fields?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the single field (`[Other Type]`) mandatory based on both conditions, you can use formula like:

```
=IF(OR([Type] = "Others", [Location] = "Others"), IF([Other Type] = "", FALSE, TRUE), TRUE)
```

If you are trying to make the two separate fields (`[Other Type]`, `[Other Location Type]`) mandatory based on both conditions, you can try formula like:

```
=IF(OR(AND([Type] = "Others", [Other Type] = ""), AND([Location] = "Others", [Other Location Type] = "")), FALSE, TRUE)
```

**Documentation**: [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

Comment: Hi Osama, does this answer help you to solve your problem? If yes, Please [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.